# react useState update not triggering with custom hook

Tags: reactjs

I made a custom hook for my player like this

```
const usePlayer = () => {
  const [volume, setVolume] = useState<number>(100);
  const playerRef = useRef<HTMLAudioElement | null>(null);
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState<boolean>(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(volume);
  }, [volume]);
  return {
    playing,
    volume,
    setPlaying,
    setVolume,
    playerRef,
  };
};
export default usePlayer;
```

I am listening for changes in another component which uses the userPlayer()

```
const PlayerButton = () => {
  const { playerRef, volume } = usePlayer();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(volume);
    if (playerRef.current !== null) {
      playerRef.current.volume = volume / 100;
    }
  }, [volume]);
  return (
    <>
      <div className="lg:mr-2 flex align-middle">
        <audio ref={playerRef} preload="none">
        <source src="" type="audio/ogg"></source>
        <source src="" type="audio/mp3"></source>
      </audio>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default PlayerButton
```

the setVolume is called like this in another component

```
  <input
     type="range"
     className="w-full"
     value={volume}
     onChange={(e) => setVolume(parseInt(e.target.value))}
     min={0}
     max={100}
         />
```

But the useEffect does only trigger inside the usePlayer component and not in the second component who uses the `usePlayer()`

any idea why ?

Comment: where is `setVolume` called?

Comment: Hi, I updated the question with the answer

Comment: So setVolume is not used in PlayerButton? If 2 different component are calling `usePlayer()` they will not share state. In order for them to share state, you need to use useContext and wrap both components in the same Context Provider.

Comment: yeah but I am using a useState inside my custom hook, which should be triggering it useEffect no because i return the useState in the usePlayer()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use setVolume in PlayerButton component, it will trigger the useEffect in PlayerButton.

**It will not trigger the useEffect if you are using setVolume in a different component.**

> **Do two components using the same Hook share state?** No. Custom Hooks
> are a mechanism to reuse stateful logic (such as setting up a
> subscription and remembering the current value), but every time you
> use a custom Hook, all state and effects inside of it are fully
> isolated.
>
> **How does a custom Hook get isolated state?** Each call to a Hook gets
> isolated state. Because we call useFriendStatus directly, from React’s
> point of view our component just calls useState and useEffect. And as
> we learned earlier, we can call useState and useEffect many times in
> one component, and they will be completely independent.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html

If you want 2 components to share state, you need to use redux or useContext to manage the state in a store.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

Example use of useContext and Provider.

```
export const PlayerContext = createContext();
export const usePlayer = () => {
    const context = useContext(PlayerContext);
    if (!context && typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        throw new Error(`usePlayer must be used within a PlayerContext `);
    }
    return context;
};

export const PlayerProvider = ({ children }) => {

    const [ volume, setVolume ] = useState(100);

    return <PlayerContext.Provider value={{ volume, setVolume }}>{children}</PlayerContext.Provider>
}
```

You need to wrap your app with the provider like this.

```
<PlayerProvider><App /></PlayerProvider>
```

Then use it like this

```
const { volume, setVolume } = usePlayer()
```

Comment: I added an example for useContext.